# Is there a way to set the MIME type of the widget in GWT

Tags: xml, gwt, encoding, mime-types

I have this scenario where I want to display the xml which is coming as a string in a dialog box based on a click event.

But now the string is showing as continuous string and does not look like a xml formatted string.

I was wondering if I could set the MIME type of any widget to say - text/xml so that the xml content is displayed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the output in a `<pre>` tag to make it monospace and formatted exactly as your Java string dictates with tabs, newlines, and whatever else you want to throw in there. An example is here: [GXT UiBinder Demo Code](http://code.google.com/p/gxt-uibinder/source/browse/gxt-uibinder-test/src/com/jhickman/web/gwt/gxtuibindertest/client/view/SourceView.java#58).

See the `getSource()` function on line 58. He's using a SafeHtml object to build a nicely formatted XML output. At some point I believe you'll have to wrap this in a `g:HTMLPanel`, or a regular `div`.

Hope that helps.

-tjw